# Redirect URL with query string to different file and maintain query string

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, query-string

I have old URLs that use the following:
mydomain.com/?page=article&cid=149&aid=1554

I had to change the name of the old index.php (which that URL above 'used'), for various reasons... and the file name is now index_180311.php. So those old links no longer work. The query string that does not change is the 'page=' part... the rest can be variable.

So what mod rewrite command would I need to make old URLs with the 'page=' query string get redirected to the new file name/path at:
mydomain.com/index_180311.php?page=article&cid=149&aid=1554

so that they work again?
I've searched the boards and tried altering other htaccess commands from other threads, but have not been successful (it usually ends up crashing my whole site), as I think I created infinite loops.

Thanks much in advance.

Comment: So what have you tried? Please add your attempts and explain what is wrong with them. How else do you expect us to help with your attempts? Or do you just want someone else to do your work for you? ;-) You see... we could only give you another suggestion and you would run into the same issue that you "can't get anything to work". That won't help anyone...

Comment: I don't fully understand all the commands, so I can't really tell you exactly what I did, other than if I go back and re-find other threads and re-alter the code to get nowhere again ;) Otherwise I would... and this time I would be sure to say what the results are other than "can't get anything to work".

Comment: Sorry, but this is not how one should try to implement something. If you go on blindly copying snippets from the internet you can as well post your passwords to some board. You need to _understand_ what you are doing! That means reading the documentation for example. Please understand that is place requires you to be able to use your tools yourself, you are required to show your effort and attempts. This is clearly explained in the "how to ask"...

Comment: Hope you're enjoying the view on your high horse

Comment: Not at all. I try to prevent you making the same mistakes I did. I realized those and started to read the documentation. Do you?

Comment: Perhaps you just didn't know what [search terms to use](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=matching+the+query+string+in+mod_rewrite).

Comment: @walf thank you! That definitely helped... ended up using and the following worked:         `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /index_180311.php?page=%1 [NC,L,R=301]`

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do an external redirect, try something like

```
# check for the presence of the page parameter (and a value)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(?:.*?&)??page=[^&]+
# silently pass requests with the parameter to the old one (the query string is passed on automatically when the substitution has no "?")
RewriteRule ^(?:index\.php)?$ index_180311.php [END]
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. That seems to work great. The only issue is that now the same content can be accessed via two different URLs - ie, https://publicresponse.com/index_180311.php?page=article&cid=884 or https://publicresponse.com/?page=article&cid=884. I don't know if that's good for SEO or has other negative effects? Thanks again.

Comment: You're right, it's not good for SEO, so don't publish links to that file. Use a canonical `<meta>` that removes the filename so they'll never end up in search results.